# Geotools StreamingRenderer point probleme when using Simplefeaturecollection instead of Simplefeaturesource using postgis database

Tags: postgis, geotools

I am developing my own cartographic server using leaflet and GeoTools in the back end, I use streaming render to draw a map in given bbox, all geometries are in 3857 coordinate reference system,here is a simple request from leaflet http://localhost:8080/server/tile/mymap/12/2083/1598.png where z = 12 and x=2083 and y=1598 when getting such request in backend i convert zxy to a reference envelope,every thing work fine so far, when i use `SimpleFeatureSource` the result in frontend with leflet looks good

```
ReferencedEnvelope env = new ReferencedEnvelope(this.getBounds(tile), this.webMercator);
for (MapLayer mapLayer : mapLayers) {
            try {
                SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = postgisDataStore.getFeatureSource(mapLayer.getLayer().getSlug());
                    Style style = createFromSLD(mapLayer);
        mapContent.addLayer(new FeatureLayer(source, style));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

saveMap(mapContent, os, mapBounds);
```

the result have not problems:

[image]

But when i use a `FeatureCollection` instead of a `SimpleFeatureSource` I get a problem with the points, they are cropped in some way ,could some one explain what happening:

```
ReferencedEnvelope env = new ReferencedEnvelope(this.getBounds(tile), this.webMercator);

for (MapLayer mapLayer : mapLayers) {
            try {
                SimpleFeatureCollection fc = featureService.getTile(mapLayer.getLayer(), tile, env);
                Style style = createFromSLD(mapLayer);
                mapContent.addLayer(new FeatureLayer(source, style));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

saveMap(mapContent, os, mapBounds);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference between your two images is the zoom level and bounding box.

Markers getting cropped at the edge of an image is a common problem in nearly all tile engines. Since each request is made using a separate request (possibly to a separate machine) there is no way for GeoTools to know what is just over the boundary and allow for it.

GeoServer uses a system of "gutters" to handle this issue, so each tile is drawn a number of pixels (based on the size of the largest symbol) bigger and then clipped to the exact tile boundary to allow it to draw the "other" half of a nearby symbol. This becomes even more complex when you attempt to handle labels as the label engine doesn't like to draw labels that go off the edge of the image so only features in the centre of your tile will be drawn, again it's worth looking at how GeoServer implements the `partials` vendor option to handle this.

At the end of the day I wonder if rolling your own tile server is worth the effort when you can use GeoWebCache and GeoServer directly and avoid reinventing these wheels. If there is some specific cartographic element that you need may be talking to the GeoServer developers would allow you to add it to GeoServer.

Comment: I don't think geoserver is the solutions specially when you develop a WebMapping application because geoserver dont give you the total control on what element to display on the map geoserver is limited to the WMS protocol for rendering map so if you need a specific feature for exemple doing some filtering on a fature collection on the business logic side in a java application using specific rules and give that feature collection to the gt-rendered later ,WMS have cql filters but they are very limited .also geowebcache my generate big a number of tile caches for even a small layer .

Comment: the probleme is not with the zoom level like i said before it works fine when you use a featureSource instead of a featurecollection even for labeling it works ,one important thing is that the issue is related to points with polygons everything is fine.

Comment: I already read geoserver source code for WMS code ant it use featureSource and streaming render i dont see any gutter method used in it.I think the tric is with geotools not geoserver,geotools is doing some technique under the hood to manage this anyway i think i will just use featuresource and drop the case,an alternative to this is using virtual tables with featureSource but i will be limited to sql queries so i can't do filtering or manipulating a feature collection in the java side,only sql queries can be used

Comment: I think the logic is in the creation of the metaTile that is cropped [here](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/e701004e988a8d0a9b7d993090c9a96dcf155e12/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerMetaTile.java#L178)

Comment: thank you ian turton i will take look at that hoping finding a solution.